# Training tensorflow on multiple GPU crashes the computer

Tags: tensorflow

We use the following hardware configuration to run multiple GPU training using tensorflow:

```
ubuntu 16.04
cuda 8
cudnn 5.1
8 titan X pascal
220GB of memory
```

The training code is based on slim as published in tensorflow/models github repository.

We are able to run the training code if we don't use all GPUs (up to 4, tested). But, once we use all 8 GPUs, the computer crashes.

What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: Do you have more information about how it crashes, and how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: From now no idea. Since we don't have any log. Each time we need to hard reboot the computer. We suspect a memory  issu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though for me it crashed as soon as I used more than one GPU. For us, the fix was to downgrade the Linux kernel to 2.6.32

More details on our problem here: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/UjB7uP7_MMU

Comment: It's weird that we have to change the kernel version in order to make it work. Perhaps, they solve the problem with the latest version.