# Computer crashes while training with tensorflow on multiple GPUs

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, tensorflow

My servers crash and automatically restart while training with tensorflow using more than one GPUs.

My task is like:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python train.py [LSTM training]
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python train.py [Another LSTM training]
```

When the tasks are both running, the server crashes and automatically restarts. I tried with different servers, but all servers behave the same.

My hardware configuration:

Dell T7610 Server
2* E5-2609 CPU
1* Nvidia GTX 1080 (Inno 3D Foundation Edition)
1* Nvidia GTX 1080Ti (Gigabyte Foundation Edition)
64G memory

My software configuration:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Linux 3.13.0-87-generic)
Nvidia Driver version 378.13 (nvidia-378 from ppa:graphics-drivers)
CUDA 8.0 (CuDNN 5.1.5)
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)
tensorflow-gpu-1.0.1 (from pip install)

The PSU has enough capacity for the graphics cards. And from memtest results, it's not a memory-related problem. There are not any `syslog` and `kern.log` log that helps to locate the problem.

I am aware of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157215/training-tensorflow-on-multiple-gpu-crashes-the-computer?rq=1). However, a workaround that downgrades the Linux kernel is unacceptable since I share the machines with lab folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I've solved the problem. I decided to answer my own question.

It's been a power issue. When the GPU draws power more than the PSU can provide, the computer restarts. Although the PSU has sufficient capacity, a 18A PCIe cable has a power limit of 217W.

My workaround is to use two PCIe power cable to power the GTX1080 with a double 6-pins to 8-pins connector.

Comment: "When the GPU draws power more than the PSU can provide" ... Do you mean "can not" ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a driver issue, too. 
can you show correct GPU device name when run 'nvidia-smi'?

Comment: It shows "Graphics Device" for 1080Ti, and "Geforce GTX 1080" for 1080.